# NPM script - Run command for each file in a folder / glob

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

Is it possible to create a NPM script that runs a command for a glob ?

Specifically, in my case, I want to run a command for each file in a folder.

For example, I want to run this command for every file in my `assets` folder:

> gltf-pipeline -i model.gltf -o modelDraco.glb -d

My `assets` folder contains a `car.gltf` and `plane.gltf` files. The project would be something like the following:

> - assets
>
>   - car.gltf
>   - plane.gltf
> - package.json

How would I go by executing that command for each file in a NPM script ?

I know how to do it as a Python script but it would be much easier if it could be done inside of NPM directly.